# How do you pass a struct that contains a String reference between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, automatic-ref-counting

In the following code snippet I am trying to create a tuple that contains a String value and a struct that contains an attribute that is set as the reference to the first value (which would be the String) in the tuple.
My question is how do I make the String (which is the first value in the tuple) live long enough.

Here is the code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct RefTestStruct {
    key: usize,
    ref_value: Option<&'static str>,
}

fn init3<'a>( cache: &Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, (String, Option<RefTestStruct>)>>> ) {
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10 {
        //create reference copy of cache
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                //lock cache
                let mut locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();

                // add new object to cache
                let tuple_value = (format!("value: {}", idx), None );
                let mut ts_obj = 
                    RefTestStruct {
                        key: idx,
                        ref_value: Some( tuple_value.0.as_str() ),
                    };
                tuple_value.1 = Some(ts_obj);
                locked_cache.insert(idx as usize, tuple_value);
    
                println!("IDX: {} - CACHE: {:?}", idx, locked_cache.get( &(idx as usize) ).unwrap() )
            });

        handles.push(handle);

    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("\n");
}

fn main() {
    // init
    let cache = HashMap::<usize, (String, Option<RefTestStruct>)>::new();
    let am_cache = Arc::new(Mutex::new(cache));

    init3(&am_cache);

    // change cache contents
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10 {
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(&am_cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();
                let tuple_value = locked_cache.get_mut( &(idx as usize) ).unwrap();
                (*tuple_value).0 = format!("changed value: {}", (*tuple_value).1.unwrap().key + 11);
                let ts_obj = 
                    RefTestStruct {
                        key: (*tuple_value).1.unwrap().key,
                        ref_value: Some( (*tuple_value).0.as_str() ),
                    };
                tuple_value.1 = Some(ts_obj);

                // locked_cache.insert(idx as usize, tuple_value);

            });
        handles.push(handle);

    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    // display cache contents
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10 {
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(&am_cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
                let locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();
                let ts_obj = locked_cache.get( &(idx as usize) ).unwrap();

                println!("IDX: {} - CACHE: {:?}", idx, &ts_obj );

            });
        handles.push(handle);

    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
error[E0597]: `tuple_value.0` does not live long enough
   --> src\main.rs:215:42
    |
215 |                         ref_value: Some( tuple_value.0.as_str() ),
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |                                          |
    |                                          borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                                          argument requires that `tuple_value.0` is borrowed for `'static`
...
221 |             });
    |             - `tuple_value.0` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2):

## How do you pass a struct that contains a `String` reference between threads?

First I answer the question in the caption and ignore the program you posted (And I'll try to ignore my itch to guess what you really want to do.)

I'll assume, you want to avoid unsafe in your own code. (So dependencies with unsafe code might be ok.)

To pass a reference to a thread, the reference has to live as long as the thread will live.

Your options:

1. Have a `'static` lifetime on your reference.
2. Use threads which have a non `'static` lifetime.

### Regarding 1. have a `'static` lifetime on the reference.

So now the questions changed into, how to obtain a reference to
a `String` with `'static` lifetime.

We can't use a constant, as we can't initialize it.

This leaves us with the possibility to [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) the `String` and [`leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) it.

But of course, this leaks memory, as the `String` can't be dropped any more. Also you get a `&'mut String` out
of it, so only one thread can have it at a time and after being
done with it, pass it on. So to me it looks like it is essentially
the same you could do with the owned value of type `String` too,
so why bother and risk the memory leak. (Putting a `Arc<Mutex<..>>` around it, is also "same you coud do with the owned value".).

Other methods might exist, which I am not aware of.

### Regarding 2. Use threads which have a non `'static' lifetime.

These are called scoped threads and guarantee, that the thread exits,
before the lifetime ends. These are not in standard rust yet, but there
are crates implementing those (I guess using unsafe).

For example [`crossbeam`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) offers an implementation of this.

Looking at your program though, I guess you want to have long lived
threads.

## The program you posted and what you probably want to achieve.

The program you posted has a different issue besides.

You try to create a self referential value in your cache. As far as I know, this is not possible in rust, without using a shared ownership tool, like [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).

If you try to use a plain `Arc`, the access would be read only and users of the cache could only change, which `String` the cache entry `points` to, but not the "pointed to" `String` itself.

So If one user replaced the `Arc<String>` in the cache, other threads would still have a reference to the "old" `String` and don't see the changed value. But I guess that is what you want to achieve.

But that is a conceptual problem, you can't have unsynchronized read access to a value, which can then be mutated concurrently (by whatever means).

So, if you want to have the ability to change the value with all prior users being able to see it, this leaves you with [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or [`RWLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) depending on the access pattern, you are anticipating.

A solution using `Arc<String>` with the aforementioned defects:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct RefTestStruct {
    key: usize,
    _ref_value: Arc<String>,
}

type Cache = HashMap<usize, (Arc<String>, RefTestStruct)>;
type AmCache = Arc<Mutex<Cache>>;

fn init3(cache: &AmCache) {
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10_usize {
        //create reference copy of cache
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            //lock cache
            let mut locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();

            // add new object to cache
            let s = Arc::new(format!("value: {}", idx));
            let ref_struct = RefTestStruct {
                key: idx,
                _ref_value: s.clone(),
            };
            let tuple_value = (s, ref_struct);
            locked_cache.insert(idx, tuple_value);

            println!(
                "IDX: {} - CACHE: {:?}",
                idx,
                locked_cache.get(&idx).unwrap()
            )
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("\n");
}

fn main() {
    // init
    let cache = Cache::new();
    let am_cache = Arc::new(Mutex::new(cache));

    init3(&am_cache);

    // change cache contents
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10_usize {
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(&am_cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();
            let tuple_value = locked_cache.get_mut(&idx).unwrap();
            let new_key = tuple_value.1.key + 11;
            let new_s = Arc::new(format!("changed value: {}", new_key));
            (*tuple_value).1 = RefTestStruct {
                key: new_key,
                _ref_value: new_s.clone(),
            };
            (*tuple_value).0 = new_s;
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    // display cache contents
    let mut handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = vec![];
    for idx in 0..10_usize {
        let cache_clone = Arc::clone(&am_cache);

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let locked_cache = cache_clone.lock().unwrap();
            let ts_obj = locked_cache.get(&idx).unwrap();

            println!("IDX: {} - CACHE: {:?}", idx, &ts_obj);
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

I am sure it is not difficult to derive the `Arc<Mutex<String>>` version from that, if desired.

That would not be as pointless, as one might think. The `Mutex` around the cache protects the `HashMap` for insertion and deletion. And the `Mutex` around the `String` values, protects the string values themselves and can be locked indepently of the `Mutex` around the `HashMap`. Usual caveats apply, if you ever need both locks at the same time, lock them in the same order always, or risk a deadlock.